# How fix My android app not working on android 9?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-9.0-pie

My android app works fine on android below 9 but on android 9 not working and app will close after run with `Myappname Keeps Stop` error on phone.

I've build app with SDKVersion & TargetSDKversion 28 ( Android 9 ) already. Please help me how can compatible my app with android 9

This is my Logcat when my app crashes , I think there is problem with background processes

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2019-12-20 18:08:33.181 9444-9499/com.example.asanbekhar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.asanbekhar, PID: 9444
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter;
        at org.scribe.services.DatatypeConverterEncoder.encode(DatatypeConverterEncoder.java:10)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.bytesToBase64String(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:51)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:46)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:32)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:151)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:126)
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:109)
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:40)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.asanbekhar-YRxDnKrurpdOW4cXsei4lA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.asanbekhar-YRxDnKrurpdOW4cXsei4lA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.scribe.services.DatatypeConverterEncoder.encode(DatatypeConverterEncoder.java:10) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.bytesToBase64String(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:51) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:46) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:32) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:151) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:126) 
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:109) 
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:40) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2019-12-20 18:08:33.192 9444-9499/com.example.asanbekhar E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter;
        at org.scribe.services.DatatypeConverterEncoder.encode(DatatypeConverterEncoder.java:10)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.bytesToBase64String(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:51)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:46)
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:32)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:151)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:126)
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:109)
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:40)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.asanbekhar-YRxDnKrurpdOW4cXsei4lA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.asanbekhar-YRxDnKrurpdOW4cXsei4lA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.scribe.services.DatatypeConverterEncoder.encode(DatatypeConverterEncoder.java:10) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.bytesToBase64String(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:51) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:46) 
        at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:32) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:151) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75) 
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:126) 
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:109) 
        at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:40) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What's the error you get in the console? Any warnings?

Comment: The first thing to do is to understand why your app is crashing. You should look at the crash in logcat (e.g. on Windows ``adb logcat | findstr com.your.app``)

Comment: @MarcLaliberté added.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin question updated with logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because android 9 and above uses SSL socket ( HTTPS Ports ) to communicate and in this case the http port used. The problem solved with adding this line below to Manifest file

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```